# Mongoose Incrament Increase Entire Object Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm in the process of trying to start save statistics on users (for a discord bot) such as command usage and so forth.

I want to save that all in my `mongodb`. Basically, I'm trying to accomplish the ability to update the db periodically from an array that saves users command usage, then cleans/wipes once the information is update on the database.

My schema is as follows:

```
const userStatsSchema = new Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    userID: String,
    commandUsage: {
        command1: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        command2: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        command3: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        command4: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        command5: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        }
    }
})
const UserStats = mongoose.model('global_users', userStatsSchema);
```

I honestly don't have much clue on where to go from here when it comes to updating them all at once. Keep in mind that the `commandUsage` array is much bigger than that, and is constantly growing.

Do I need to increment each individually or is there a better way?

```
$inc: commandUsage: { command1: 5, command2: 8, command3: 2, command4: 0 }
```

Any help in figuring this out would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you clarify little more on the question? Always you want to increment all the fields of `commandUsage` object? Or you know which field of `commandUsage ` to increment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [bulk operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/index.html) to be executed at a fixed interval (time or number of occurence)

```
const UserStats = mongoose.model( 'global_users' );
const bulk = UserStats.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
const maxNbrOfCommandAtOnce = 1000; // if you want to use an interval based on the nbr of commands
const interval = 10000; // to set an interval  of 10 sec

let saveBulkInterval = setInterval(executeBatch, interval);

const onCommand = function(event) {
    // I guess here that you have the ID of the item you to modify
    bulk.find({_id: itemId}).update({$inc: {event.commandName: 1}});

    if (bulk.s.currentBatchSize === maxNbrOfCommandAtOnce)
        executeBatch();
};

const executeBatch = function() {
    if (bulk.s.currentBatchSize > 0) {
        bulk.execute(function() {
            bulk = UserStats.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question.